# Discord.py kick all members of server

Tags: discord.py, try-except

My code:

```py
@client.command(pass_contxt=True)
async def kick_all(ctx):
    members = ctx.guild.members 
    members.remove(ctx.me)
    for member in members:
        try:
            if member.id != id or member.id != id: # the two ids inputed(don't want to share my id)
                await member.kick(reason="deleting server")
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"Failed to kick {member}.")
        except discord.Forbidden: # forbidden error is the error that gets returned when the bot is forbidden to do something(in this case kick itself)
            await ctx.send(f"Failed to kick {member}.")
        continue
```

Assume that discord is already imported. This code doesn't give me any errors because of using try/except, but it only works once and then stops because it can not kick itself(yes it starts at first to try to kick itself).

P.S. I wanted to learn how to do this because simply deleted my own server would be no fun and wouldn't help me learn.

Also, Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def role_kick(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    [await member.kick() for member in ctx.guild.members if role in member.roles]
```

This will kick all members that have a certain role, so if you assign everyone with a members role and do `[prefix]role_kick [the role]` it will kick all people with that role.
For example `>role_kick @members`

Hopefully this solves your solution

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```py
your_ids = (1234, 5678) # paste you'r ids hear

@client.command()
# me: this is a command, dpy: OK
async def kick_all(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Wait A Second...') # I am alive
    if ctx.author.is_owner() or ctx.author.id in your_ids:
        # This is a check for user, if user is you or server owner will be 
        await ctx.send('Started') # Start
        continued

        members = ctx.guild.members      # This is list of members
        members.remove(ctx.me)           # a user can't kick you'r self so remove bot

        for member in members:           # creating a loop
            try:                         # a bot is limited and limit is Error
                if member.id in your_ids: # Check member is not you
                    await member.kick(reason="omae wa mou shindeiru")
                    # Kick

                else:
                    await ctx.send(f"Failed to kick {member}.")
                    # This is an log for user.

            except Exception as err: # bot has not permission
                await ctx.send(f"Failed to kick {member}.")
                # This is an log for user.
                continue # Next user
    else:
        await ctx.send('You don\'t have permission to use this command.')
```

bot need `members` intent so this is how the client is defined

```py
from discord.ext.commands import *
import discord

intent = discord.Intents.default()
intent.members = True
# or 
intent = discord.Intents.all()

client = Bot(command_perfix='?', intent=intent, ...)
```

And check it [image]

Comment: I tried your code but all it outputs os "Failed to kick Smiley Face" and then it stops kicking  anyone else.

Comment: bot need "Kick members" permission.

Comment: bots in general cant kick themselves right? also, my bot has admin role which is at the top of the rankings and gives it perms to anything(everything enabled)

Comment: check [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents), you need [`members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.members) Intents.

Comment: but how do we use it? all the documentation says is to do client.intent.

Comment: I get the errpr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    intent = discord.Intent
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Intent'

Comment: there was a spelling error in the code. i edited it.

Comment: it still fails to kick my own bot, then proceeds to stop kicking anything else

Comment: This is not made by me (at least)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: This is a completely separate issue, your problem is solved and it has nothing to do with the relationship. As for how we do such a thing, it takes a lot of time to implement it as well.

Comment: how is this unrelated? my original problem was that it trys to kick itself but fails, then stops kicking other people.

Comment: @client.command()
    async def leave(ctx):
        await ctx.guild.leave()

Comment: no i dont want it to leave the server I want it to continue to kick other members after failing kicking itself.

Comment: check my answer again .

Comment: I dont see how your answer is different can you please explain?

Comment: If you do not have a problem, can you tell me how old my audience is to explain it more appropriately?

Comment: ok first of all, my problem right now is that you said "check my answer again" but I don't see a difference.

Comment: also im a middle schooler if that helps

Comment: oh now i see the change but when we set list members to be the members of tthe guild, then remove the bot, shouldn't we change the for loop to 

    " for member in members: "

Because if we do 

   " for member in ctx.guild.members: "

we won't being using the list members meaning the list we use will still have the bot in it.

Comment: I tried that but it didnt really work but it didnt return any error or say something like "Failed to kick member name." 
P.S look at the updated question(updated my code :) )

Comment: what's you'r python and discoed.py version? My version is `python:3.8.1` and `discord.py==2.0.0`(can use 1.7.3). And it should be noted that since this command is dangerous, I can not test it.

Comment: I added two lines to the code to see the reaction. Please test it and if it does not work send me the output

Comment: pretty sure im using 3.8.1 too and for discord.py I installed it and then reinstalled it so I'm assuming the latest version. also, it does say started im pretty sure the problem is somewhere in the lines of my bot crashing or having a run time error saying "event loop is closed"; I know this because it happens after I make it so the code stops running.

Comment: try again with second Intents. (answer edited)

Comment: turned on both pressence intent and server intents but still doesn't work

Comment: idk, sorry bro.